# Java8: ConcurrentHashMap.compute atomicity

Tags: java, concurrency, java-8

I am trying to use ConcurrentHashMap.compute to implement something and I cannot figure out if my logic is 100% threadSafe and correct.
Javadoc says about `compute(K key, BiFunction<? super K, ? super V, ? extends V> remappingFunction)` method:

> Attempts to compute a mapping for the specified key and its current
>   mapped value (or null if there is no current mapping). The entire
>   method invocation is performed atomically. Some attempted update
>   operations on this map by other threads may be blocked while
>   computation is in progress, so the computation should be short and
>   simple, and must not attempt to update any other mappings of this Map.

The question is: Can I pass a function having side-effects to this method? Is there any guarantee that the function is applied only once even if there are other threads trying to update the same key?

LE: As requested, this is my update function (tries to generate an event and remove the cached updates from map):

```
final Set<UniqueID> updatedIds = new HashSet<>(updatesMap.keySet());
for (final ID id : updatedIds) {
    updatesMap.compute(id, (modifiedId, updates) -> {
        final Event event = createEvent(modifiedId, updates);
        threadPool.addEvent(event);
        return null;
    });
}
```

I must be sure that there is only one event created from each updatedId.

Comment: Yes, in case of `ConcurrentHashMap`, you have this guaranty. As long as these side effects do not include other manipulations of the same map. Though, it’s strongly recommended to apply side affects to the contained value only, as anything else will soon become unmaintainable.

Comment: Regarding your example, `createEvent` and `threadPool.addEvent` may still get invoked with other parameters if someone does the same operation for a different key concurrently. Besides that, why do you copy `updatesMap.keySet()` into a new `HashSet` before iterating?

Comment: There is no problem if someone invokes createEvent or threadPool.addEvent at the same time for another key. I have decided to copy the keySet before iterating because the iterator has weak consistency and I want to avoid the situation when  2 separate events are created for the same id in the same iteration (remove id + create event, someone adds that id again and it is iterated again)

Comment: Do you need to access an `updates` from its `id`, *i.e* `map.get(id)`?

Comment: @Holger though you are right, we had a defect where someone decided to lazy load services via `CHM::computeIfAbsent`, with dependencies on other services too. In simpler words `computeIfAbsent` was updating not only it's Key/Value but some other from the Map - this would lead to a dead-lock... increasing the capacity to a very large value, so that re-sizes would not happen was "provided" as a solution - which I disagree with to this day also. So to the OP point: whatever you said counts as an answer.